# How to version a joomla website?

Tags: version-control, joomla

How can I version a Joomla website.

When I do a hand made web application I put the code and database schema into SVN and add a script that updates a working copy, sets up a database and resets a server.

With Joomla I am lost :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same approach with joomla too.

1. First, install joomla where it is accessible via our web server
2. take a dump of the mysql database and put it into some directory also inside the root folder where joomla was installed.
3. create a script that imports your database dump into mysql.
4. move the rootfolder away from where you installed it and import everything into your scm.
5. checkout the joomla installation to exact place where it was installed into originally.
6. run the script that you made in step 3 to import your database.

Now if you work on the site, you edit your stuff and commit, you can checkout the latest changes in the joomla folder.  And if you mix branches as "release versions" of your site, things are abit easier. Also, you could make a shell script that does combine the checkout and mysql dump import..

Answer (score 0):

There is a versioning component: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring/content-submission/6260/details This will only take care of the core content and will *not* hook into SVN though.

Answer (score 0):

It very much depends on whether you want to version control:

1. code changes
2. configuration
3. content

I've put those in order of likelihood and difficulty; i.e. I'm hoping you *don't* want to version control the content, partly because that's more complicated.

You also need to take into account whether you want to version control third-party components. If you're not eidting their code - and, ideally, you shouldn't be - there's little to gain in doing that.

So, version controlling your own extensions is straightforward - just add the appropriate directories to SVN and set up ignore files for everything else.

Configuration is stored partly in configuration.php, but also in the database. You can certainly version-control the file, but the database side of things is probably best handled with regular dumps, which will also include the content.

Generally speaking, it's awkward to use a version control system as a backup mechanism, so I'd advise you handle backups by regular rsync's of the filesystem coupled with automated database dumps. SVN is better suited to your day-to-day development and keeping track of what code changes you've made.

Does that sound workable?